Как поменять цвета у ссылок <a>
Подскажите пжл!
У меня на весь экран  "main"
Внутри него  "header" (представляет собой верхнюю горизонтальную полоску)
В DIV "header" находится 6 div - один для хранения лейбла, и 5 для хранения в них ссылок .
Пытаюсь через CSS поменять шрифт текста в ссылках но не получается. ??? Спасибо
========================HTML====================
<body>
    <div class="main">      
        <div class="header">            
           
            <div class="img_div">
            <img name="img1" id="img1" class="img1_header" src="img/logo.png">          
            </div>  

           
            <div class="header_elem"> 
            <a href=# сlass="ahref">О клубе</a>
            </div>

            <div class="header_elem"> 
            <a href="#" сlass="ahref">Направления</a>
            </div>

            <div class="header_elem"> 
            <a href="#" сlass="ahref">Родителям</a>
            </div>

            <div class="header_elem"> 
            <a href="#" сlass="ahref">Детям</a>
            </div>

            <div class="header_elem"> 
            <a href=# сlass="ahref">Педагогам</a>
            </div> 
            
        </div>
</div>

===============================CSS==========================
.header_elem{
    
    font-size: 1.6em;

    color: black;
    height: 70px;
    width: 170px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 5px 500px 150px;
    
    border-style: dashed;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: white; 
    
 }

 .ahref{
    

    color: black;
   
    
 }

 .ahref:link {
  color: black;
 }

 .ahref:visited {
  color: black;
 }


У Вас кириллическая c в атрибуте class

Спасибо огромное. Как Вам удалось это увидеть?

Просто скопировать Ваш a тег в IDE

Sublime text видимо не видит этого, спасибо Вам еще раз.
